# Angular 5 - Clear localStorage when browser is closed

Tags: angular, angular5

I am using Angular 5 for my web application. I want to clear the localStorage objects, whenever the user closes the browser window.

```
 @HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"])
clearLocalStorage(event) {
    localStorage.clear();
    console.log('####Destroy local storage####');
}
```

I cannot stick the above code in the main **app.component.ts** due to other logics such as SSO in the application.

Is there a way, i can perform this action globally in the angular app with different approach.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local storage is not a good option in your case.

**Local Storage** - Stores data with no expiration date, and gets cleared only through JavaScript, or clearing the Browser cache / Locally Stored Data.

While the **Session Storage** - stores data only for a session, meaning that the data is stored until the browser (or tab) is closed.

So use Session Storage for your purpose. It will be cleared automatically on browser closing.

Comment: But you can not share the data between tabs if you are using Session Storage.

Comment: yeah. the app will not have any data, even if the logged in tab is open and another duplicate tab is opened, when using sessionStorage

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessionStorage instead.

> [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

If you using the approach you mentioned. If you open 2 tabs at the same time, when you close one tab, the localStorage will be cleared.

Comment: I mean if you use `localStorage` and clear whenever `beforeunload` event happened, then `localStorage` will be cleared and it will affect all the opened tabs. `sessionStorage` will be cleared automatically when the session end (browser closed)